# Python: Persistent shell variables in subprocess

Tags: python, shell, variables, subprocess, persistent

I'm trying to execute a series of commands using Pythons subprocess module, however I need to set shell variables with export before running them. Of course the shell doesn't seem to be persistent so when I run a command later those shell variables are lost.

Is there any way to go about this? I could create a /bin/sh process, but how would I get the exit codes of the commands run under that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen` takes an optional named argument `env` that's a dictionary to use as the subprocess's environment (what you're describing as "shell variables"). Prepare a dict as you need it (you may start with a copy of `os.environ` and alter that as you need) and pass it to all the `subprocess.Popen` calls you perform.

Answer (score 5):

Alex is absolutely correct. To give an example

```
current_env=environ.copy()
current_env["XXX"] = "SOMETHING" #If you want to change some env variable
subProcess.Popen("command_n_args", env=current_env)
```