# How to set shell variables in subprocess.Popen (in a less ugly way...)

Tags: python, unix, shell, subprocess, freebsd

NOTE: This is *not* the same question as [Python: Persistent shell variables in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126116/python-persistent-shell-variables-in-subprocess), as that question is actually about environment variables, not shell variables.

I'm trying to automate a basic benchmark that I'm doing in csh using the shell built-in `time` command.  You can tweak the output of `time` by setting the variable of the same name in the shell like follows:

```
set time=(1000000000 "%U %S %E %P %W %X %D %K %M %F %R %I %O %r %s %k %w %c")
```

However, this is of course not an environment variable, so you can't pass it in the `env` parameter in the `subprocess.Popen` constructor (I tried that first...).  You *can* hack it together by abusing (imo, anyhow) the `cmd` argument to do that, and then your actual work (shortened to display nicely):

```
time_cmd = 'set time=(1000000000 "%U %S %E %P %c"); time ./some_func'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, executable="/bin/csh", shell=True, ...)
```

and that works as you would expect, but it seems not really the right way to go (and can lead to some pretty horrible `cmd` construction when you want to tweak a bunch of different shell behaviours).

Is there any other way to set shell variables in `subprocess` other than this kludge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a limited number of options to communicate to a child process (invocation arguments, environment, and streams).  Since setting a shell variable is in a more general sense modifying a child process's internal state, what you call a "kludge" is actually quite reasonable.  I don't know of any csh variants that have a special way to load shell variables.

However, you could neaten it up by writing all your initialisation commands to the shell via a pipe, or even writing them to a file and having them read by csh's `source` builtin.

Comment: This is probably a good way to look at it (unfortunately).  While most shells seem to have shell variables, their behaviour undoubtably isn't governed by POSIX in the way that environment variables are.  Unfortunately I haven't found the proper magic sauce to communicate with an actual *shell* via pipe.  This seems more like a job for pyexpect or custom tty munging, both of which are less appealing than my existing solution. :-)