# Read Bash variables into a Python script

Tags: python, bash, scripting, environment-variables

I am running a bash script (test.sh) and it loads in environment variables (from env.sh). That works fine, but I am trying to see python can just load in the variables already in the bash script.

Yes I know it would probably be easier to just pass in the specific variables I need as arguments, but I was curious if it was possible to get the bash variables.

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source env.sh

echo $test1

python pythontest.py
```

env.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

test1="hello"
```

pythontest.py

```
?
print test1 (that is what I want)
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You need to export the variables in bash, or they will be local to bash:

```
export test1
```

Then, in python

```
import os
print os.environ["test1"]
```

Comment: I am curious, is there an easy way to export all of the variables?

Comment: @TallPaul The `os.environ` dictionary already contains all variables that can be seen by the program.

Comment: `set -a; source env.sh; set +a`. The `-a` option instructs `bash` to export each new variable until you turn it off with `+a`.

Comment: Instead of using 'export',  you can also set it in front of your command - in this case, it will apply ONLY to your command: 'test1=wibble python myscript' - NOTE: there is no semicolon in front of the 'python' - this is intentional.

Answer (score 8):

There's another way using `subprocess` that does not depend on setting the environment. With a little more code, though.

For a shell script that looks like follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
myvar="here is my variable in the shell script"

function print_myvar() {
    echo $myvar
}
```

You can retrieve the value of the variable or even call a function in the shell script like in the following Python code:

```
import subprocess

def get_var(varname):
    CMD = 'echo $(source myscript.sh; echo $%s)' % varname
    p = subprocess.Popen(CMD, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
    return p.stdout.readlines()[0].strip()

def call_func(funcname):
    CMD = 'echo $(source myscript.sh; echo $(%s))' % funcname
    p = subprocess.Popen(CMD, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
    return p.stdout.readlines()[0].strip()

print get_var('myvar')
print call_func('print_myvar')
```

Note that both `shell=True` shall be set in order to process the shell command in `CMD` to be processed as it is, and set `executable='bin/bash'` to use process substitution, which is not supported by the default `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Kinda I have 20 envs and I need to source 20 file to get all of them.
Could you help to write get_var from one source and not from each run? How is that possible to do?

Comment: @IvanShelonik I guess you can change the bash code given in `CMD` variable to `echo` multiple variables line by line and run the same code. You'll also need to change the `return` statement as follows: `list(map(strip, p.stdout.readlines()))` so that the retrieved list of variables are returned.

Comment: Why in the world would you start all these command substitutions? `echo $(something)` has no benefit over just `something` -- it's a slower, buggier way to do the same thing ("buggier" in part because of missing quotes, and in part because [`echo` itself is poorly specified](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)). And if you're going to substitute Python variables into strings parsed as code by a shell, you ought to be using [`shlex.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) to escape them appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the environment variables that get set are permanent, which I think they are not. You can use `os.environ`.

```
os.environ["something"]
```

Comment: add `set -a` before the `ource` command (on a separate line). This says, that from now on, any variable set should automatically be exported.

Comment: @TallPaul, it is as AMADANON Inc. says. However you can set variables for the current environment [from python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1339904/322909).

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to source a file, the thing you are missing is `set -a`.  For example, to source `env.sh`, you would run:

```
set -a; source env.sh; set +a.
```

The reason you need this is that bash's variables are local to bash unless they are exported.  The -a option instructs bash to export all new variables (until you turn it off with +a).  By using `set -a` before `source`, all of the variables imported by `source` will also be exported, and thus available to python.

Credit: this command comes from a comment posted by @chepner as a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17435116/2800876).

Answer (score 0):

Two additional options, which may or may not help in your specific situation:

Option 1:

if env.sh only contains regular NAME=value, get python to read it (as a text file) instead.

This only applies if you control the format of env.sh, and env.sh doesn't contain any real shell commands, and you control the containing shell script.

Option 2:

In the shell script, once all the necessary variables are set, either save these to a file, or pipe them as stdin to your python script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source env.sh

echo $test1

set | python pythontest.py
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
source env.sh

echo $test1

set > /tmp/$$_env
python pythontest.py --environment=/tmp/$$_env
```

You can then read the file (or stdin), and parse it into e.g. a dictionary.